# How wealthy are state legislators in Texas?

Tags: united-states, local-government, public-sector-compensation

Something you see in political publications from time to time is a piece about "the top 50 wealthiest members of Congress", or "the average wealth of senators".  However, I've found that information about local state legislators is scant or unavailable.

In my state, Texas, state legislators are paid very little in salary.  It is my speculation that while this seems romantically righteous (citizen legislators, not milking their position for money), it has the practical effect of excluding everyone except doctors, lawyers, and the independently wealthy.  Are there any documented sources that can tell us what the personal wealth of Texas legislators is?  Anything regarding total net worth, annual income, or the like is welcome.

Comment: Are you interested in wealth or income? If wealth, are you using the common definition Stocks, Bonds, Land, Businesses, etc. For example, a farmer may make $40k-$50k per year, but they have millions of dollars of wealth. Conversely, a new doctor may have little wealth because of student loans. Why not just ask what the former occupation (or current) of the last X years of state legislators.

Comment: @user1873 any information is better than no information.  Really I'm interested in *net worth*, which would take into account liquid vs non-liquid assets as well as debt.  The point is to see that our local legislators, as a group, are vastly more wealthy than they would be if legislators were paid a sufficiently high salary.

Comment: "vastly more wealthy than they would be if legislators were paid a sufficiently high salary." That would require a comparison to other states. Perhaos all 50 to get a good dataset. If you want [financial disclosures for 2012](http://blog.chron.com/texaspolitics/2013/05/searchable-database-of-cy-2012-texas-officials-financial-statements/), the chron put out a recent one.

Comment: @user1873 yep, I'm aware of the need for comparison, but that's not what I'm asking for.  I'm only asking for data on Texas legislators.  Those disclosures posted by The Chronicle are interesting, but they don't go as far as I'm looking for because they only address "activity" rather than absolute wealth.

Comment: "they only address activity rather th absolute wealth." That isn't true. The chron's link to financial disclosures is an assets and liabilities listing, very similar to the national one at [Open Secrets](http://www.opensecrets.org/pfds/overview.php?type=W&year=2011). **What exactly are you looking for?**

Comment: @user1873 I'm sorry, but it just isn't so.  Look here, for example: https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/699296-andersoncy2012.html.  I've looked at several and they're all like this.  This filing is simply a declaration of various interests, but it doesn't disclose their values, and there's nothing there about income or other assets.  I think I have thoroughly explained what I am looking for, and this just isn't it.

Comment: I think it is what you wantExamine pg4 that you linked. It lists mutual funds held, acquired, or sold. Anderson held/acquired between (1k-5k) of [USAA Growth&Income](http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/USGRX/f?t=USGRX) worth $21.08 a share. Total asset value of $21k-$105k. He has 2 more funds in the same range, and 3 or so in the 100-00 range. The document also lists liabilities, and Real property (pg10),  and business interests. I suppose you could run Zillow on the properties. What makes you think this information differs much from the national disclosures, which you seem to find acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very old question, but I will share what I found.

The following eBook, *[Texas Politics Today 2017-2018 Edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=bsu5DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA173&lpg=PA173&dq=texas%20state%20legislature%20members%27%20net%20worth%20-congress&source=bl&ots=2RzQsIVmYW&sig=ACfU3U0gUCIGPb8R9D4A3_lA01HshBxQsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf74zex6LhAhWP3oMKHSU6CRIQ6AEwLHoECGIQAQ#v=onepage&q=texas%20state%20legislature%20members%27%20net%20worth%20-congress&f=false)*, from Google with limited access is available and indicates that the legislators' full worth are not precisely reported.  See the image below.

[image: Texas Politics Today 2017-2018 Edition]

This is definitely worth making an issue about with the Texas' State Legislature so that its citizens can more easily access and be informed about the net worth of its legislators.